# Can I access a subclass object's properties through a superclass reference in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, instance, parent

Let's say I have a class called Food and in the constructor it has attributes for price, # of calories, and a description.

I also have a subclass of Food called Burger, and the Burger has an additional attribute for type of meat.

Now if I create an array of Food instances that contains instances of the Burger class, can I access the type of meat attribute through the array?

Sorry if this is confusing, but I want to know if I can (and how) I can access parent and child properties in an array of parent and child objects. I am using Java too.

Comment: You will have to cast : ((Burger)foods[index]).getMeatType

Comment: A constructor does not have properties.  Only object instances have properties.  Your question should be "Can I access a subclass object's properties through a superclass reference"

Comment: Sweet, thank you. Could you try to explain what exactly is happening? Is the Food instance being cast into a Burger instance?

Thanks for the clarification. So a constructor has attributes and an object has properties?

Comment: Not quite. Attributes and properties are the same thing.  A constructor is an executable method, and only object instances have properties (well, static properties actually belong to the class itself).  See my answer below for a discussion of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the properties of a `Burger` even if it is stored in an array of `Food`. First you will need to cast it to a `Burger` so your program knows what type it is. Since not all objects in your array of `Food` are `Burger`s, it is a good idea to check its type first. Something like this:

```
Food[] myFoods; //your food array
if (Burger.isInstance(myFoods[0])) { //check that the Food is a Burger
 ((Burger)myFoods[0]).meatType; //cast the object to a Burger and access its property
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. The way I have it now is that I have two separate arrays, but now I can have just one array of objects.

Comment: @Skistar002 Happy to help! If this solved your issue I would really appreciate an upvote or an accept.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the subclass `Burger`'s `meat` attribute is specific to that subclass, so the only option is to downcast the `Food` object to `Burger`, at the time you want to access its Burger-specific properties.  This is fraught with problems if your collection (array) contains different subclasses, as the cast can fail.

```
Food[] foods = new Food[n];
Food[0] = new Burger(...);
Food[1] = new Vegetable(...);
Meat m1 = ((Burger)foods[0]).getMeat(); // This is OK
Meat m2 = ((Burger)foods[1]).getMeat(); // ClassCastException
```

Or better

```
for (Food f : foods)
{
    if (f instanceof Burger)
    {
        Meat m = ((Burger)foods[0]).getMeat(); 
        // other Burger-related processing
    }
    else if (f instanceof ...someothersubclass)
    {
         ...
```

This tends to be rather brittle, but you can't use polymorphism to streamline things here.  Runtime (dynamic) dispatch works only for overridden methods.  Overloaded methods in the same class are resolved at compile time.